# SQL Server the closest 1st February

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please help in finding the closest February 1st to current date?

The following script works correctly only if it is ran in current year:

```
select DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, -1, GETDATE()), 0))
```

But when it would be ran in January next year it will produce incorrect result.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this using `IIF` and `DATEFROMPARTS`

```
select IIF(month(getdate()) > 2,
       DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Getdate()),2,1),DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Getdate())-1,2,1) )
```

If you are using older versions then

```
select Case When month(getdate()) > 2 
         then CAST(CAST(YEAR(getdate()) as char(4))+'-02-01' as date)
         else CAST(CAST(YEAR(getdate()) - 1 as char(4))+'-02-01' as date)
       end
```

Comment: Good idea with comparing number of current month and number 2. Thank you, Prdp!

Comment: I think you have an extra closed parentheses in your bottom statement. and shouldn't 20170102 return 20170201 @DavidFreeman since Feb 1 2017 would be the closest to Jan 1 2017?

Comment: @scsimon - Updated.. Thanks bro

Comment: No sweat-- @prdb

Comment: I'll use only idea of current approach, not exactly this code.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be interpreted two different ways:  the first being to find the next closest Feb 1 (i.e. `Feb 2 2016` will return `Feb 1 2017`), and the second being to find the closest Feb 1 to the current date (i.e. `Feb 2 2016` will return `Feb 1 2016`).

Prdp has already supplied an answer for the former, so this approach (which I'm sure can be simplified) will be for the latter.

This will consider the current year's Feb 1 and the next year's Feb 1, and compute the `DateDiff()` in days from both, and select the closest one.

```
;With Dates As 
(
    Select  ThisFeb = DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()), 2, 1),
            NextFeb = DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()) + 1, 2, 1)
), Distance (Date, Distance) As
(
    Select  ThisFeb, Abs(DateDiff(Day, GetDate(), ThisFeb)) As ThisFebDiff
    From    Dates
    Union All
    Select  NextFeb, Abs(DateDiff(Day, GetDate(), NextFeb)) As NextFebDiff
    From    Dates
)
Select   Top 1 Date
From     Distance
Order By Distance Asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN 
DATEDIFF(dd,CAST(CONCAT(year(GETDATE()),'-02-01') AS DATE),GETDATE()) < 183 
THEN CAST(CONCAT(year(GETDATE()),'-02-01') AS DATE)
ELSE CAST(CONCAT(year(GETDATE())+1,'-02-01') AS DATE) END as ClosestFebFirst
```

Comment: 'Closest' in future :)

Comment: @DavidFreeman i'd add that to the original question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible solution...

```
DECLARE @SomeDate DATE  = '2017-06-30';

SELECT TOP 1
    ClosestFebFirst = CASE WHEN dd.Diff1 < dd.Diff2 THEN pd.D1 ELSE pd.D2 END 
FROM
    ( VALUES (
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@SomeDate),     2, 1),
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@SomeDate) + 1, 2, 1)
            )
        ) pd (D1, D2)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
            ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, @SomeDate, pd.D1)),
            ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, @SomeDate, pd.D2))
            )
        ) dd (Diff1, Diff2);
```